# Get Unique object of JSON

Tags: json, angularjs, lodash

I have this kind of array:

```
var foo = [ { "a" : "1" }, { "b" : "2" }, { "a" : "1" } ];
```

I'd like to filter it to have:

```
var bar = [ { "a" : "1" }, { "b" : "2" }];
```

This is my [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MLWLE3xyWf6LXndztL8u?p=preview)

At line 7 in [**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/MLWLE3xyWf6LXndztL8u?p=preview)  when i write `return JSON.stringify( x );` it is good but returning string JSON.. But when i write `return x;` it becomes bad and does not return Unique JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by simply using `uniq`, not requiring collection:

```
var uniqueList =_.uniq(foo, function( x ){
    return JSON.stringify(x);
});
```

Updated plunk here: http://plnkr.co/edit/KYW6UybdiBxuvOVX8naP?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

```
first you can download underscorejs then you can use the following code

 var foo = [{ "a": "1" }, { "b": "2" }, { "a": "1" }];
            var result = _.uniq(foo, function (obj) {
                return JSON.stringify(obj);
            });


 refere the following url  http://underscorejs.org/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var uniqueList =_.uniq(foo, 'a');` Here is doc: https://lodash.com/docs#uniq
here is plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/HkirGPrs3dGZMUEnEKiT?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for very simple solution.. :)

Comment: Just to note, I was almost going to put this as my answer, but realised that while it works per the given array, if `b` happened to contain the duplicate it wouldn't work.

Comment: Wow, http://plnkr.co/edit/oaLhZNejHXbOpSIq3El6?p=preview, I am just not sure any more. `uniq` is doing some weird things.

Comment: Uniq work so: it takes element from array and match it with each element in array by properties which you point.